How to set Content-Type when using @fastify/static?
I use @fastify/static to serve my SPA. Everything works fine when developing. When I deploy behind reverse proxy (Nginx), reverse proxy adds header Content-Type: "text/html" for every file type. Browser refuses to execute .js files with error:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I suppose Nginx adds header because it is not present. When testing locally, I see that Content-Type header is not present.
How to add proper Content-Type to @fastify/static handler?
Or should I configure Nginx to not add header?
